# invalid number: not a valid number string ':i_s' at function to_int()

Tags: sql, abap, hana

I am trying to fetch data from a HANA view through a program in `se38` based on SQL queries. I have declared a variable status date type c which will contain the value of today's date. Now, when I am trying to pass this variable it is giving the error as `invalid number: not a valid number string ':i_s' at function to_int()`.

```
variable-> i_status_date(8) type c.
```

I am trying to pass this value with `('PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$STATUS_DATE_DM$$', ':i_status_date')`.

I have also checked in HANA view which is the only input parameter for this having data type NVARCHAR. Also tried changing the data type of variable as date and Integer but still facing the same issue.

Can anyone please help and guide how to overcome through this problem?

Comment: You have to pass the value of your ABAP variable instead of its name.   Try to build your SQL statement string in ABAP like this:      Sql_statement = |Select ... ('PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$STATUS_DATE_DM$$', '{ i_status_date }')|.

Comment: Hi Christoph,  i tried to build my SQL statement as suggested by you but still it is giving the same error "invalid number: not a valid string '{i_s' at function to_int()"

Comment: Then you forgot to put a space after the opening curly brace and before the closing one .

Comment: Hi Christoph Thanks for your Efforts but still i am getting the same error  "invalid number: not a valid number string '{ i_' at  function to_int()".

Comment: Please put the complete ABAP statements into your question, not only fragments.